# How to solve javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer

Tags: java, android, ssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

Am trying to send http request using volley but am receiving error

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer

I google around and try some suggestions but none solve my problem. please help

Bellow is the code am using

```
public class volley {

    static RequestQueue queue=null;
    public static String TAG = "MY_VOLLEY";
    volley(final String URL,
           final String Text
           final Context context
    ){
        helper.log(TAG,"Started Loading");
        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        if(queue==null) {
           queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        }
        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(
                Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
                return;
            }
        }
    ){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                try {
                    params.put("message",Text);
                    params.put("from",From);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    helper.log(TAG, "Error, hash map failed");
                }
                return params;
            }
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return params;
            }
    };
        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of debugging the JSSE is a pain in the ...

Most likely the handshake fails and JSSE most of the time only shows you the final problem, i.e. that the server is closing the connection. Quite often the server is telling you the problem in an TLS alert message but that doesn't show up in the exception message.

If you have Wireshark or something similar installed, the easiest way is to fire up a session and look at the TLS-records (Wireshark shows them quite nicely so it's easy to recognize the error-packet containing the error-code and meaning).

If you don't have that tool, yet, you can activate SSL-debugging and look at the messages on STDOUT. Be warned that they are a bit hard to read if you're unfamiliar with TLS and - since it's a global setting - you should make sure that your tests happens when no other TLS-connection is established, otherwise you get mixed outputs. To enable TLS-handshake debugging, set the system property `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake`

Comment: An alert always results in an exception containing it. The close is probably dime to the client not supplying a certificate when required, as this isn't an alert condition.

Comment: @user207421 That's definately not the case. I'd wish it were because that would make my life a lot easier if it were. I have to support that type of problem quite regularily and often enough end up using Wireshark or said system property.